# useDebounce test sometimes fails, but sometimes doesn't

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a function that relies on a provided value which changes after it hits a certain delay.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function useDebounce<T>(value: T, delay = 500): T {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedValue(value);
    }, delay);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(handler);
    };
  }, [value, delay]);

  return debouncedValue;
}
```

I've also written a test for it:

```js
import { renderHook } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";

describe("useDebounce", () => {
  test("if it changes content after debounce time", async () => {
    const testVal = "test";
    const testChangedVal = "changed-test";
    const testDebounce = 50;

    const { result, rerender } = renderHook(() => useDebounce(testVal, testDebounce));

    rerender({ value: testChangedVal });

    setTimeout(() => {
      // THIS LINE APPEARS IN THE OUTPUT OF THE SECOND TEST FOR SOME REASON AND FAILS THE PIPELINE
      expect(result.current).toEqual(testChangedVal);
    }, testDebounce);
  });

  // THIS ONE FAILS LIKE 50% OF THE TIME
  test("if it does not change content before debounce time", async () => {
    const testVal = "test";
    const testChangedVal = "changed-test";
    const testDebounce = 50;

    const { result, rerender } = renderHook(() => useDebounce(testVal, testDebounce));

    rerender({ value: testChangedVal });
    expect(result.current).toEqual(testVal);
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(result.current).toEqual(testVal);
    }, testDebounce / 2);
  });
});
```

It's function is simple. However, there's like a 50% chance that it fails on the pipeline and I'm not sure why the output looks like the one from the test suit above. The problem usually magically disappears when re-trigger the whole pipeline when it installs every module from scratch. What could be wrong here?

The failed test output:

```
FAIL src/hooks/useDebounce.test.tsx (21.502 s)
  ● useDebounce › if it does not change content before debounce time
    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
    Expected: "changed-test"
    Received: "test"
      16 | 
      17 |     setTimeout(() => {
    > 18 |       expect(result.current).toEqual(testChangedVal);
         |                              ^
      19 |     }, testDebounce);
      20 |   });
      21 | 
      at setTimeout (src/hooks/useDebounce.test.tsx:18:30)
      at Timeout.task [as _onTimeout] (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:391:19)
```

Comment: Usually, if you are working with the clock, as in setTimeout, you would use [Timer Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks) to set specific datetime and progress the clock to simulate time being passed in a controlled way, including for setTimeout.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky But why did the two test suites get mixed up? Could it be the reason?

Comment: Unless you specify, test order execution is not guaranteed. There is an option that you can try, [runInBand](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--runinband) that runs the tests sequentially/serially, but this may only be a short term solution (what if you move tests to different files). Opinion, but you really shouldn't have tests depend on other tests, as in you should be able to run a test without any dependence on other tests.